# Issue with migrating jQuery code to angular 6

Tags: css, angular

I try to create this clock in my angular - 6 app (installed jQuery )

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/DawidKrajewski/pen/pvJaYa)

I'am trying to draw hours inside my .ts file code like that:

```
  createClock() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var radius = 6;
    var clockEl =  this.clock.nativeElement
    $(document).ready(function() {
      for(var i=0; i<60; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        clockEl.append(li);
      }

    });
```

But the `<li>` css class want append to my DOM

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: If you're using Angular, why not just append values to an array and use `*ngFor` instead? Manually creating DOM elements is almost never the correct answer in an Angular app.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery where almost never is 0.00001% of the cases ;)

Comment: if you have to use jquery in angular, you aren't using angular correctly

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be done by Angular alone. But if you want to use jquery and its already installed. Make use you import it in the component by using

```
import * from 'jquery';
(or)
declare var $: any;
```

Also make sure its added in angular.json as

"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I deleted jQuery and transformed all the code to TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clock',
  template: `<div class="whole-page vertical-middle">
  <div class="vertical-middle__child">     
    <div class="clock">
      <ul class="clock__marks">
          <li *ngFor="let number of numbers"></li>
        </ul>      
      <div class="clock__hands">
        <div #clockHour class="clock__hand clock__hand--hour"></div>
        <div #clockMinute class="clock__hand clock__hand--minute"></div>
        <div #clockSeconds class="clock__hand clock__hand--second"></div>
      </div>      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>`,

  styleUrls: ['./clock.component.scss']
})
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('clockHour') clockHour: ElementRef
  @ViewChild('clockMinute') clockMinute: ElementRef
  @ViewChild('clockSeconds') clockSeconds: ElementRef

  public numbers = [];
  private radius = 6;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2) {

    this.clockHour = el.nativeElement;
    this.clockMinute = el.nativeElement;
    this.clockSeconds = el.nativeElement;
    this.numbers = Array(60).fill(1);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createClock()
  }


  createClock() {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    const second = currentTime.getSeconds() * this.radius;
    const minute = currentTime.getMinutes() * this.radius + Math.floor(second / (this.radius * 10) * 10) / 10;
    const hour = currentTime.getHours() * this.radius * 5 + Math.floor(minute / (this.radius * 2) * 10) / 10;

    this.setClockHands(second, minute, hour)
  }

  setClockHands(second, minute, hour) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.clockSeconds.nativeElement, 'transform', 'rotate(' + second + 'deg)')
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.clockMinute.nativeElement, 'transform', 'rotate(' + minute + 'deg)')
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.clockHour.nativeElement, 'transform', 'rotate(' + hour + 'deg)')

    const interval = 1000; //1 second
    let before = new Date();


    setInterval(() => {
      const now = new Date();
      const elapsedTime = now.getTime() - before.getTime(); //Fix calculating in inactive tabs
      const delay = Math.round(elapsedTime / interval);

      second += this.radius * delay;
      for (var i = 0; i < delay; i++) {
        if (((second - i) * this.radius) % (this.radius * 5) === 0) {
          minute += 0.5;
          if (minute % this.radius === 0) {
            hour += 0.5;
          }
        }
      }

      this.renderer.setStyle(this.clockSeconds.nativeElement, 'transform', 'rotate(' + second + 'deg)')
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.clockMinute.nativeElement, 'transform', 'rotate(' + minute + 'deg)')
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.clockHour.nativeElement, 'transform', 'rotate(' + hour + 'deg)')
      before = new Date();
    }, interval);
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help